# Mirror on Github

Tags: git, github

I'm working on the Android sourcecode and I want to create a mirror of my code on Github. Here's the status:

1. Checked out android code using instructions on source.android.com
2. Created a local branch, checked it out, made changes, committed the changes to local repo

Now, since I don't have commit rights on Android's origin repo and I want to make my code available to everyone publicly, I don't know how to do that. I've created a repo on github but there are two problems with pushing to github (a) it's a huge repo (b) I will have problems updating it when I 'repo sync' again from the origin android source.

The question: I'm looking for a strategy for making my code available publicly while still being able to fetch/merge/pull from the origin repository from Google.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android/kernel_common

Click "Fork".

Comment: That only gets the kernel. I need to work on other projects as well. Also, since Android has now moved away from kernel.org and this project is a mirror of the one at kernel.org, this won't work for future updates.

Comment: There are other repos on there, and I'm sure someone has a mirror of the current source on GitHub you can use instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: That's the thing. There is none. At least none that I can find. CynogenMod is using the old mirror too but that isn't being updated anymore.